# Add dictionary to list in python not working

Tags: python

So below is my code: 
I am getting none type object is not iterable error as append is not happening.

```
result_list_haops=[]
each_result={'name': 'ads-scin-tracking', 'monitoringGroup': 'HAOPS', 'azkabanInstance': 'lva1-war-waraz01', 'project': 'ads-metrics-pipeline', 'subscribers': ['ads-relevance@linkedin.com'], 'invalid_attribute': 'teamAskAlias', 'link': 'https://intake2.corp.linkedin.com:8767/#/flows/view/lva1-war-waraz01/ads-metrics-pipeline-ads-scin-tracking'}
group = each_result['monitoringGroup']
        self.log.debug(group)
if group == "HAOPS":
    result_list_haops = result_list_haops.append(each_result)
```

Later in my code,

```
result_grouped_by = sorted(result_list,key=itemgetter('subscribers'))
```

it throws Nonetype object is not iterable.

I am unable to find what is it I am doing wrong here.

Error i am getting: 
Nonetype object is not iterable

Desired behaviour:

```
result_list_haops=[{'name': 'ads-scin-tracking', 'monitoringGroup': 'HAOPS', 'azkabanInstance': 'lva1-war-waraz01', 'project': 'ads-metrics-pipeline', 'subscribers': ['ads-relevance@linkedin.com'], 'invalid_attribute': 'teamAskAlias', 'link': 'https://intake2.corp.linkedin.com:8767/#/flows/view/lva1-war-waraz01/ads-metrics-pipeline-ads-scin-tracking'}]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Hint: Notice how the code (correctly) **does not** say `result_grouped_by = result_list.sort(key=itemgetter('subscribers'))`? What would go wrong if you tried that instead? Now, do you see why the same logic would apply to `.append` as does to `.sort`? (What do those two methods have in common?)

Answer (score 1):

`append` doesn't have return statement so it returns default `None`, which changes `result_list_haops` from list to `None`. Don't use assignment

```
if group == "HAOPS":
    result_list_haops.append(each_result)
```

Comment: could you suggest the changes i need to make for my code

Comment: @user1795999 I did, remove `result_list_haops = ` and use it like in the answer.